# add value to the property of an object literal using get & set

Tags: javascript

Here i have an object called myobj and it has only one property which is  'age'. I want to add another property called 'name' using object.defineProperty()'s get and set methods.But i had to use a variable for that.That means the variable holds the value i passed to 'set' method ,not the myobj.name itself.console.dir(myobj) shows both the age and name property of the myobj object and the value is there assigned to myobj.name property.But if a variable is holding the value then how it is assigned to myobj.name property??

[image]

```
var myobj={age:2};

(function(){

var name;
Object.defineProperty(myobj,'name',
{
    enumerable:true,
    get:function(){
         return name;

    },
    set:function(val){

       name=val;
    }


});


myobj.name='jack';
})();
for(i in myobj){
   console.log(myobj[i]);
}
console.dir(myobj);
```

Comment: It might seem silly, but that's just how they decided to make it. It's magic. You can use these magic methods to do things like mask other objects like the DOM, and make the observer pattern. It's all taken care of in the javascript engine.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking... but how about: this.name = val;

Comment: i tried it .this.name=val is throwing an error in my console.

Comment: Why? Do you want it assigned directly?

Comment: @MaxBumaye this.name = val; will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: i could assign it directly using 'value: '.there would be no more confusion like this if i can assign it directly.this code is only to see how things actually works.

Comment: @QuentinEngles  why it cause infinite recursion??can you clarify the reasons please??

Comment: @user3138436 If you use this.name = val; inside the set function you'll get another call to the set function because `this.name`, and `myobj.name` both call that set function. It's a magic call made by the javascript engine on the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question it's implementation specific. All the javascript engines are going to do it different. Like in the case of Chrome there's going to be a C++ code that interacts with your setter, and getter to magically cause these things to work.

Here is a good example of why it works the way it does. With this the DOM element is masked so it makes a shorter way to get, and set it. I have changed the `name` variable to an input element to demonstrate this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="getset">
<script>
var myobj={age:2};

(function(){

var name = document.getElementById('getset');
Object.defineProperty(myobj,'name',
{
    enumerable:true,
    get:function(){
         return name.value;

    },
    set:function(val){

       name.value=val;
    }


});
name.addEventListener('click', function(){
    myobj.name = 'clicked jack';
    console.log(myobj.name);
});

myobj.name='jack';
})();
for(i in myobj){
   console.log(myobj[i]);
}
console.dir(myobj);



</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: name is not an html element.Then how you can add an event listener to it??i didn't get the "name.addEventListener(...)" statement??can you please explain

Comment: In this context the variable name is element, or what ever you want. It's safe to put what ever you want inside those get/set functions as long as you're careful of the usual errors.

Comment: actually what confuses me is how 'input :text' value is assigned to 'jack' in the first place??

Comment: It's the `name.value=val` part in the set function. It's magic. Object.defineProperty creates `magic methods` on properties.

Answer (score 1):

> But if a variable is holding the value then how it is assigned to myobj.name property??

It's not assigned to `myobj.name`, but `console.dir()` enumerates all properties including the one that you have defined (backed by a variable).

To create a private property using `.defineProperty()` you could do it like so:

```js
function Foo(age)
    {
        var name = 'jack';

        this.age = age;

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
          enumerable:true,
          get: function() {
              return name;
          },
          set: function(val) {
              name=val;
          }
        });
    }

var f = new Foo(33);
alert(f.name); // "jack"
```

#### Update

Although the property will not appear in the `for..in` loop unless enumerable is true, `console.dir()` may not honour that setting (e.g. Chrome).

Comment: But if i put enumerable to false it is still there

Comment: @user3138436 I find that hard to believe and my browser confirms that; i.e. setting enumerable to false will make the property disappear from `console.dir()`.

Comment: @user3138436 Is it still there in the for loop?

Comment: As it is false by default i removed the 'enumerable:true,' statement form the code and checked.i am using chrome..

Comment: @user3138436 If it still gets inside the loop it is a bug, but like Jack I doubt it. You should try it in a different browser.

Comment: @user3138436 Using Safari and either removing the enumerable:true or making it false yields the same result; the property disappears from console.dir() and doesn't show in the for loop.

Comment: it might be an error but i double checked it.It disappeared from the for...in loop but console.dir still showing the name property ( '-' )

Comment: @user3138436 Then I suppose `console.dir()` doesn't play by the same rules ;-)